# Connecting to Oracle PDB via ODBC

Tags: oracle, odbc

I have a LOCAL Oracle 19c database.  I am trying to get ADO to connect to it.  The first step is to get ODBC working. I have one PDB container called orclpdb, which is what I want to use. I can connect from SQL*Plus...

```
Y:\INSTALL_UNZIP\bin\sqlplus.exe acs/<Password>@localhost:1521/orclpdb
```

I go into the 64-bit ODBC Administrator, and had to fight a little bit (adding OCI_LIB32 and TNS_ADMIN paths), but finally got the ODBC Admin tool to connect, but ONLY to the root/system database. My root question is 'How do I get ODBC administrator to connect to a specific container DB?

Within the ODBC Administrator, the TNS Service Name field dropdown only shows ORCL, not orclpdb.  Again, I can connect using ORCL, but as system/.

UPDATE:  Due to issues such as this, I switched most apps to Devart's Oracle Data Access components to Delphi.  They have a DIRECT mode, which does not need SQL*Net or TNS stuff
.

Comment: Does your tnsnames.ora file (in the TNS_ADMIN directory) have an entry for orclpdb?

Comment: No it did not.  So each container needs a separate TNS_NAMES entry...So I have added it, and I can connect. That gets me to the next step in the process.  Submit as answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your TNS_ADMIN/tnsnames.ora file has an entry for the PDB (orclpdb).

Comment: For all the simple work I do with ODBC, I just use the Easy Connect syntax for the PDB in my odbc.ini file, e.g. `ServerName = localhost/orclpdb1`  This means I don't use tnsnames.ora.